# How to set back the old value of radio button when user select No from confirm Box?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a problem that I have to trigger the User confirm box when the user makes the change on the radio button.

I successfully trigger the Confirm Box but challenging for me to set the old value in the radio group.
Anyone has any idea to do that.
I tried solution mention on google but no luck.

```
Ext.define('CustomRadioField', {
override: 'RadioField',
setListeners: function(config) {
    var me = this;
    config.listeners = {
            change: {
                fn: function(control, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
                    var me = this;
                    me.fieldChanged();
                    Ext.Msg.confirm(MyFunction.T('Confirm'), "Are you sure want to delete?", function(btn) {
                        if (btn == 'no') {
                            //Added my logic to reset back
                            control.suspendEvent('change');
                            control.setValue(oldValue);
                            control.resumeEvent('change');
                            //End
                           //Added to refresh page not to reload but this location.reload post to my server insted to refresh.
                            location.reload();
                        }
                        if (btn == 'yes') {


                        }
                    });

                }
            },
            scope: me
        },
        focus: {
            fn: me.storeFocusField,
            scope: me
        },
        afterrender: {
            fn: function(f, e) {
                me.setFieldFocus;

            },
            scope: me
        },
        boxready: {
            fn: me.setUpChangeEvent,
            scope: me
        },
        specialkey: {
            fn: function(f, e) {
                var me = this;
                switch (e.getKey()) {
                    case e.TAB:

                        break;
                }
            },
            scope: me
        }
};
},

});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume you have two radio buttons. If so, call setValue(true) on the other radio button and the radio group will change the selected radio button for you

Answer (score 0):

can you attach the code?

You can use `field.reset()` function to reset field value, where **field** is radio button field or you can use `form.reset()` method to reset all fields in form to state before user change.

Comment: Code added in my post. I have marked the issue in code using block line